# fdisk - partition in single line

Tags: linux, command, fdisk

Can you create a partition in a usb disk using fdisk command in a single line.

fdisk command is interactive in nature, But I want to automate partition creation in a single line using fdisk command.

Comment: Do you want to erase everything and create a single partition, or create a new partition with given start / end?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Trying to automate `fdisk` is possible, but it is not easy to maintain.  As other answers note, either [parted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/) or [sfdisk](https://superuser.com/questions/364876/what-does-sfdisk-do-and-how-does-it-compare-to-fdisk-or-parted) are designed to do what you want and are easier to automate.

## parted

To create a partition in one line with `parted`:

```
parted -a optimal /dev/usb mkpart primary 0% 4096MB
```

as seen in [this UNIX SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49274/79839).  Each of the parts is pretty self-explanatory, but just in case here is how `mkpart` is defined:

> `mkpart` [*part-type* *fs-type* *name*] *start* *end*

where things in square brackets are optional, but you probably want `primary` for your *part-type*, *start* at `0%` and end at `4096MB` or however large your USB stick is.

Comment: FWIW, the options specified here are no longer supported by sfdisk and results in an error for the above snippet.

Comment: @chicks How is `sfdisk` any easier to script? Input for `sfdisk` is just as messy as it is `fdisk`.

Comment: I hope most people choose `parted`.  I will remove the `sfdisk` section to reduce confusion.

Comment: As I used `badblocks` before, my whole disk was erased and I received an  error like "**Error: /dev/nvme1n1: unknown partition table**" (in German: "Fehler: /dev/nvme1n1: unbekannte Partitionstabelle") when using the above command. I had to first create the partition table with `parted /dev/nvme2n1 mklabel gpt` and then create the partition with `parted /dev/nvme2n1 mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%` After that I formatted it with `mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme2n1p1`.

Answer (score 7):

Erase everything, and create a single partition:

```
dev='/dev/sdb'
sudo umount "$dev"
printf "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw\n" | sudo fdisk "$dev"
sudo mkfs.ext4 "${dev}1"
```

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/332252/creating-and-formating-a-partition-using-a-bash-script

Comment: this works but using `sfdisk` or `parted` will be easier to get working and maintain

Comment: @chicks cool, I will have a look at it. Someone should have posted an example :-)

Comment: good point @Ciro, I will take care of that...

Comment: `echo ",,;" | sfdisk /dev/sda` In `,,` the first parameter is the offset if you need to be sure to maintain it, the last one partition type is `8e` for LVM on msdos and `E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928` for gpt. Check parameters `--no-reread --no-tell-kernel` if updating online and parameters `--append` and `-N` if you don't want to erase everything.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use the [parted](http://linux.die.net/man/8/parted) command instead of fdisk.

Comment: Could you show an example of how to use the parted command?

Answer (score 2):

`sfdisk` also has a non-interactive mode that reads in partition information from stdin. `parted` is more flexible, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use [sfdisk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk) instead.

The sfdisk man page is a little confusing, here's some [specific examples](https://www.codeblog.org/viewsrc/util-linux-2.12r/fdisk/sfdisk.examples) of how to automate partition setup with sfdisk.  One example is you can save the partition info from one drive via `sfdisk -l` and then dump that directly on to a new drive.

Comment: The link no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

For GPT tables you can use [sgdisk](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sgdisk):

```
sgdisk -n 0:0:0 /dev/sde
```

> -n, --new=partnum:start:end
>                 Create a new partition. You enter a partition number, starting sector, and an ending sector. Both  start  and
>                 end  sectors  can be specified in absolute terms as sector numbers or as positions measured in kibibytes (K),
>                 mebibytes (M), gibibytes (G), tebibytes (T), or pebibytes (P); for instance, 40M specifies a  position  40MiB
>                 from  the  start of the disk. You can specify locations relative to the start or end of the specified default
>                 range by preceding the number by a '+' or '-' symbol, as in +2G to specify a point  2GiB  after  the  default
>                 start  sector, or -200M to specify a point 200MiB before the last available sector. A start or end value of 0
>                 specifies the default value, which is the start of the largest available block for the start sector  and  the
>                 end  of the same block for the end sector. A partnum value of 0 causes the program to use the first available
>                 partition number.